# Why Cloudera Manager reports that disks are full?

Tags: linux, hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager

Cloudera Manager reports that disks are full on some nodes of my Hadoop cluster but, checking manually the free space with `df -h`, every disk is almost half-empty.

Is it a bug or I need to issue some other commands to check the actual free space ?
What command is Cloudera Manager using when doing health check ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The property `dfs.datanode.du.reserved`was set to 100GB, so Hadoop could not use that amount of space (for each volume) for storing new HDFS blocks.